# Swift 4: removing UISearchbar's editing shadow

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to `swift`, i built an application with search feature,

when the view loads, the `searchBar` is fine, but when it begins editing, a shadow appears i want to remove it

i tried this code at `TextDidChange`, but it didn't work

```
searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
searchBar.isTranslucent = true
searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

[Screenshot Before Editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI5o8.png)
,
[Screenshot After Editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEb5.png)

code:

```
func addSearchbar(){
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        let scb = sc.searchBar
        scb.showsCancelButton = false

        if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            //navigationbar.tintColor = UIColor.green
            //navigationbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        }

         navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.green
         navigationItem.searchController = sc
         navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
         navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
         navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, all those arrows, I don't even know *where* to look.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth, when i click the uisearchbar a shadow and a cancel button appears next to the scb, i want to remove the shadow

Comment: u cant , better to use normal text field with button . u can achieve it

Comment: @JoyalClifford, can you post the answer

Comment: your using UISearchController or UISearchBar

Comment: @JoyalClifford, question updated